# Thread Sleep in one Async Task pauses other Async taks in application

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

Let's say I want to sleep thread in one async task.

Code:

```
 protected Weather doInBackground(Void... params) {
       try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
}
```

This causes other async task in application to pause. Why?
My intention is not to pause the thread, but network call takes some time, which pauses all async task in application.

How to solve this issue?

This is how I'm calling async task

```
WeatherAsync weatherAsync = new WeatherAsync(Pref.getString(getApplicationContext(), Pref.local.WEATHER_CITY), null, null,
                new WeatherAsync.WeatherAsyncCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPreExecute() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPostExecute(Weather result) {
                        if (result == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        Log.d("Temp", "" + result.getTemp());
                        //adapter.addWeather(new NavigationDrawerItem(result, NavigationDrawerItem.WEATHER_VIEW));
                    }
                });
        weatherAsync.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` API documentation says the following:

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

That is to say, if you're running a relatively modern Android, your `AsyncTask`s are happening in the same thread. To continue from the API documentation:

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

This is just one way of doing multi-threaded stuff on Android. You could just as well do plain old threads to achieve multi-threading.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this. I have view pager which loads 4 fragmnets. 2 of them and main activity executes total 4 asyc task. if one them stucks then everything stucks. How to fight this issue?